# Attribute of Element Via Selector Without Using Eval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element for which I have the selector, and I want to retain its ".alt" attribute and add it to an array.

Previously, I had been using

```
fakeArray.push(eval($("selector here").alt))
```

I think I've run into an issue with the scope of eval being global, wherein I get this error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at eval ...
```

The odd part is that my code runs fine and the array works unless I make it a proper function. For example, this would NOT work:

```
function testFunction (){
    // code here
}
```

If I just ran the code inside the function by itself it would work, though.

I'm wondering if there's any alternative to eval that works in the local scope with selector attributes. Also, any method other than $("selector here).alt to retrieve that alt value would be very helpful.

I'm currently running my code via console in Chrome Dev Tools, and it only works in the specific context/scope that I'm working in. It wouldn't run in 'top'.

Comment: have you included jquery script ?

Comment: Yes, my script runs after both the page and jquery have been completely loaded.

Comment: I don't get it, did you put javascript in the `alt` attribute, and now you're trying to run it with `eval` and return the result to an array ? If so, stop doing that!

Comment: anywho `document.querySelector('selector here').getAttribute('alt')`

Comment: There's a text value of the alt attribute that I'd like to retrieve. I've been using eval($('selector').alt) to get that text value. I have the element's selector and I'm trying to avoid using eval because 1) it doesn't work and 2) because I now realize it's bad practice to use it.

Comment: Why are you using eval though? Wouldn't $("selector").props("alt") work to get the text?

Comment: I was using eval to execute  $("selector").alt then add that result to the array. I couldn't figure out how else to retrieve that value from $(...).alt. I'm attempting to use the querySelector option right now.

Comment: Thank you so much adeneo, if you add your `document.querySelector('selector here').getAttribute('alt')` answer, i'll select it as best- that has solved my issue entirely. - To clarify for future readers, even though I had $('selector').alt I still had to execute it to retrieve that alt value somehow. I used eval for that- though the document.querySelector... solution works perfectly because it simply returns the attribute's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't want to use `eval` here. In fact, there are very rare cases to use `eval` anymore. It is considered dangerous, and really shouldn't be used anymore. There are ways to do what you want without using `eval`. See [the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

To get the alt attribute, it should be as simple as doing `$('selector').attr('alt')`. Although it might be nice to see a snippet or example of your code to verify that this is what you want.

**Edit:** As mentioned by user adeneo in the question comments, you don't even need to use jQuery by instead calling `document.querySelector('selector').getAttribute('alt')`.